# With a strict smart / presentational component split, how to send updates to a presentational component about an event it triggered?

Tags: asynchronous, events, vuejs3, components

I have the following setup:

- A presentational component `ItemCard` with a save button that triggers a "save" event
- A smart component `ItemList` that has a list of `items` and for each item creates an `ItemCard`
- A central logic to manage the logic for `items`, including an async `save` function to send the data to the API

*ItemCard.vue*

```html
...
    <div v-if="loading" class="spinner"></div>
    <button v-else @click="saveInput">Save</button>
```

```js
...
const saveInput = () => {
  emit('save', inputText.value);
};
```

*ItemList.smart.vue*

```html
    <ItemCard
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      @save="() => mockSave(index, $event)"
...
```

```js
const mockSave = async (index: number, value: string) => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  items[i] = value;
};
```

As long as the `save` event only communicates one way, this is fine. The event is raised from `ItemCard` to `ItemList`, and `ItemList` can trigger the correct API calls.

However, what happens if I want to communicate information the other way? For example, I would like to display a spinner on the `ItemCard` where I clicked the save button.

This would mean displaying information on a particular presentational component that somehow relates to a specific action (in this case the "save" event triggered by this component).

Here are possible solutions I have thought of so far:

1. Directly pass the `save` function as prop to the presentational component, call it, and use the function return value to retrieve updates. This would basically work, although I rarely see functions passed as props in vue 3, so I'm unsure about this solution.
2. Give the "save" event a unique ID, and use props or an event bus to send back the "response" to the presentational component. While this would work, it seems cumbersome and like a bit of a hack.

Please check this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-e4bayy?file=components%2FItemList.smart.vue) for further details on the situation I'm referring to.